# $d(f)(a) =d(g)(a)$ if $f^\prime(a)=g^\prime(a)$ for a linear operator $d$

Tags: derivatives, linear-transformations

Let $E=\mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ be the space of indefinitely differentiable real functions. Suppose that $d$ is a linear operator of $E$ such that

$$d(fg)=f d(g)+ g d(f)$$ for all $f,g \in E$.

Suppose that $f^\prime(a)=g^\prime(a)$ for a given $a \in \mathbb R$. How to prove that $d(f)(a) =d(g)(a)$?

I tried to use the similar relation of the derivative than the one of $d$ and the linearity of $d$... without success so far. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma), there exists $h_1,h_2\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ smooth maps such that $h_1(a)=f'(a)$, $h_2(a)=g'(a)$ and which satisfy:
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=f(a)+(x-a)h_1(x),\\g(x)&=f(a)+(x-a)h_2(x).\end{align}$$
By linearity of $d$ and since $d(1)=d(1\times 1)=d(1)+d(1)$, one has that $d$ is zero on constant maps. Therefore, one gets:
$$\begin{align}d(f)(a)&=h_1(a)d(x-a),\\d(g)(a)&=h_2(a)d(x-a).\end{align}$$
Whence the result, since $h_1(a)=f'(a)=g'(a)=h_2(a)$.

---

I would like to give more insight on this exercise:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, linear maps $d$ on $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ which satisfy:
$$d(fg)=fd(f)+gd(g)$$
are called global derivations on $M$. Using the multivariate  Hadamard's lemma, one can show that for all derivation $d$ on $M$ there exists a unique vector field $X$ such that:
$$d(f)(a)=T_af\cdot X(a).$$
This is precisely what we have shown in dimension $1$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $X(a)=d(x-a)$.

As I see that you are French, if you are interested in learning more about global derivations, I recommend reading Chapter 3 of *Introduction aux variétés différentielles* by J. Lafontaine.

Comment: Merci. Je n'avais pas pensé à utiliser le lemme d'Hadamard. Qu'est ce qui t'a "mis la puce à l'oreille" ? Cette relation avec les variétés différentielles?

Comment: J'avais déjà étudié la preuve concernant les dérivations globales sur les variétés différentielles. Sinon, j'imagine que c'est naturel d'utiliser le lemme d'Hadamard parce qu'on travaille avec des formes locales d'applications lisses.